# Multiply Columns Together Based on Condition

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Is there a way for me to dynamically multiply columns together based on a value in another column in Python? I'm using Polars if that makes a difference. For example, if `calendar_year` is 2018, I'd want to multiply columns `2018`, `2019`, `2020`, and `2021` together, but if `calendar_year` is 2019, I'd only want to multiply columns `2019`, `2020`, and `2021` together. I'd like to store the result in a new column called `product`. In the future, we'll have additional columns such as `2022`, and `2023`, so I'd love the ability to have my formula account for these new columns without having to go into the code base each year and add them to my product manually.

| id | ... | calendar_year | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ... | 2018 | 0.998 | 0.997 | 0.996 | 0.995 | 0.994 | 0.9801 |
| 456 | ... | 2019 | 0.993 | 0.992 | 0.991 | 0.990 | 0.989 | 0.9557 |

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to multiply CY factors for all years beyond `calendar_year`, and not have to update this logic for each year.

If that's the case, one way to avoid hard-coding the CY selections is to use `melt` and filter the results.

```py
(
    df
    .select([
        'id',
        'calendar_year',
        pl.col('^20\d\d$')
    ])
    .melt(
        id_vars=['id', 'calendar_year'],
        variable_name='CY',
        value_name='CY factor',
    )
    .with_column(pl.col('CY').cast(pl.Int64))
    .filter(pl.col('CY') >= pl.col('calendar_year'))
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        pl.col('CY factor').product().alias('product')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ product  │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 456 ┆ 0.970298 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 0.982119 │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

From there, you can join the result back to your original dataset (using the `id` column).

Comment: @Max Herring: May I add that the recommendation of using `melt`, i.e. to change your data structure, should, if possible, be taken a step further. Adding new data points/years as columns rather than rows makes it quite difficult to do analysis, as you need to operate on column names as if values. So you quickly end up with regexes. This can easily go wrong. For instance, the solution above assumes your calendar years are 2000 and further, it will break if you include 1999. That is a reflection of your data model being sub optimal. If you can change it, I would strongly advise to do so.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could use the `np.where(condition,then,else)` function to do that.
Do you want to create a new column with the result of that operation? This could work

```
df['2018_result'] = np.where(df.calendar_year.isin(['2019','2020','2021']),df.2019*df.2020*df.2021, 'add more calculations')
```

Would be great if you can provide more details :)

Comment: Hey @Selknam_CL , yes, I'd like to store the result of this operation in a new column as you've done. Thanks for pointing me towards the np.where() function. I added some additional details too. Each year there will be a new column added to the dataframe, so I'd love to avoid referencing columns by name if possible. Is this doable? Let me know if you need more details :)!

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use a numpy function here, Polars is perfectly capable as @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ shows.

Comment: Polars has pl.when().then().otherwise () that should always be preferred over numpy.

Comment: Thanks, @ΩΠΟΚΕΚΡΥΜΜΕΝΟΣ! Worked like a charm. And btw, @ritchie46, awesome work with the Polars module. My coworkers and I have been absolutely loving it!